# remove "no errors" output from show errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, output, sqlplus

Using the oracle setting I was already able to strip away most of the superfluous messages from the oracle output. The problem I am hitting now are my calls to show errors. When no errors are detected it prints "No errors." to the screen and to the log. Anyway know of a way to turn this off as well?

currently using:

> set serveroutput on size unlimited format wrapped;
>
> set feedback off
>
> set verify off
>
> set trimspool on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. But you can use an alternative to `show errors`, querying the `user_errors` table directly, which with `set feedback off` will not show anything if there are no issues. With an error you see the problem:

```
set feedback off

create or replace procedure x42 as
begin
nul;
end;
/

select line, text
from user_errors
where type = 'PROCEDURE'
and name = 'X42'
order by sequence;
```

.. gives output:

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

     LINE TEXT
--------- --------------------------------------------------------------
        3 PLS-00201: identifier 'NUL' must be declared
        3 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

With valid code:

```
create or replace procedure x42 as
begin
null;
end;
/

select line, text
from user_errors
where type = 'PROCEDURE'
and name = 'X42'
order by sequence;

prompt finished
```

... you see nothing (except the prompt added for effect):

```
finished
```

Of course, that does mean you have to tailor each query to match the preceding statement, which might be error-prone. You might prefer to wait until the end of the script and get all the errors together:

```
select type, name, line, text
from user_errors
order by type, name, sequence;
```